# Java - Eclipse - The declared package "edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.examples.basic" does not match the expected package ""

Tags: java, eclipse, crawler4j

I am trying to set up the example code for [Crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/), but Eclipse is throwing an error that I don't understand. The error is:

```
The declared package "edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.examples.basic" does not match the expected package ""
```

The path "edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.examples.basic" is there and correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the Java compiler from the base directory, so that it sees the `edu/...` folder.
If you run it from the directory with the actual `.java` file, it won't see any folders, so it will expect the default package.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "run the Java compiler from the base directory". The package is in a .jar-file and from whereever I add it, Eclipse can't find it. Every other "import"-command works, for example: "import edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.CrawlConfig;"